# Reverse a transition on props change with styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components

I am animation two elements on a props change: a container div slides in/out with `max-height`, and the contents of the div fades in/out with `opacity`.

Trouble is, I want the container to animate after the contents on the "out" animation, but I want it to appear before the contents on the "in" animation. Currently, the elements always go in the same order: contents transition first, then the container. This means that the contents appear before the container has slid in on the "in" animation.

I've tried using the `reverse` attribute and `keyframes` from styled-components, but honestly I'm so bad at CSS animations that I can't begin to understand what I need to change.

Here's the current code:

Component.tsx

```js
export default function Component() {
  const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(true);

  const handleAccept = () => {
    setShowBanner(false);
  };

  const handleReject = () => {
    setShowBanner(false);
  };

  return (
    <StyledComponent $showBanner={showBanner}>
      <StyledText>
        // some text
      </StyledText>
      <StyledButtonsContainer>
        // some buttons
      </StyledButtonsContainer>
    </StyledComponent>
  );
}
```

Component.styles.tsx

```js
export const StyledComponent = styled.div<{ $showBanner: boolean }>`
  &&& {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: ${zIndex("overlay")};
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: ${(props) => (props.$showBanner ? "100%" : "0")};
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.secondary};
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.white};
    transition: max-height 0.5s 0.5s ease;

    @media ${device.tablet} {
      border-radius: 0 0 2px 20px;
    }

    * { // targeting everything all of the contents
      opacity: ${(props) => (props.$showBanner ? "100%" : "0%")};
      transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this by controlling the `transition-delay` property with the `$showBanner` prop. I did it via the `transition` shorthand, though:

```
export const StyledCookieBanner = styled.div<{ $showBanner: boolean }>`
  &&& {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: ${zIndex("overlay")};
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: ${(props) => (props.$showBanner ? "100%" : "0")};
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.secondary};
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.white};
    transition: max-height 0.5s ${(props) => !props.$showBanner && "0.5s"}; // here

    @media ${device.tablet} {
      border-radius: 0 0 2px 20px;
    }

    * {
      opacity: ${(props) => (props.$showBanner ? "100%" : "0%")};
      transition: opacity 0.5s ${(props) => props.$showBanner && "0.5s"}; // here
    }
  }
`;
```

This reverses the delays for the two transitions, effectively reversing the transition.